# Align text vertically inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, text, carousel

I'm trying to use bootstrap carousel with using only text. I need to get the text to be aligned in the middle. However, the text tend to be on left instead aligned in the middle as it should be. I'm trying to get this fix.

```css
.carousel{
   display:table;
   width:100%;
}
.carousel-content {
    color:black;
    position:flex;
 width:inherit;
 text-align:center;  
    height:200px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                            <h3>#1</h3>
                            <p>This is a twitter bootstrap carousel that only uses text. There are no images in the carousel slides.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                            <h3>#2</h3>
                            <p>This is another much longer item. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, sint fuga temporibus nam saepe delectus expedita vitae magnam necessitatibus dolores tempore consequatur dicta cumque repellendus eligendi ducimus placeat! Sapiente, ducimus, voluptas, mollitia voluptatibus nemo explicabo sit blanditiis laborum dolore illum fuga veniam quae expedita libero accusamus quas harum ex numquam necessitatibus provident deleniti tenetur iusto officiis recusandae corporis culpa quaerat?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                            <h3>#3</h3>                            
                            <p>This is the third item.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

</div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.carousel-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the updated fiddle fixed.
Check it.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qooffpf3/1/)`enter code here`